# How to load .gltf/.glb model into Three.js app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, three.js, quasar-framework

I went through a few similar topics here on SO but I can't find a solution to my problem. The issue is that `.glb` model doesn't load at all. My Vue app uses webpack (I use Quasar framework which has built-in webpack). I configured Webpack to bundle `.glb` files (I read that `file-loader` is sufficient here). It doesn't help. My model sits in `assets` folder. Some say that 3D model should be placed in `public` (or `static`) folder. I've tried it and both solutions don't work in my case.

I loaded model to `main_three.js` and updated webpack in `quasar.conf.js`. Here is a reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-mendeleev-3e1zoy?file=/src/store/model/main_three.js

**main_three.js**

```
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load("~assets/Flower.glb", (glb) => {
  state.scene.add(glb.scene);
});
```

**quasar.conf.js**

```
chainWebpack(chain) {
  chain.module.rule('glb')
  .test(/\.glb$/)
  .use('file-loader')
  .loader('file-loader')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will work:

```js
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
      loader.load("../assets/Flower.glb", (glb) => {
        state.scene.add(glb.scene);
      });
```

put **../** in front of assets/Flower.glb in the file url.
i think that will work because when we use the ~ operator, it does -(A + 1) where A is the value to the right of the tilde. For example, we'd get -2 if we did this (since -(1 + 1) = -2):

```
**~**['apples', 'oranges'].indexOf('apples'); // => 0
**~**['apples', 'oranges'].indexOf('oranges'); // => -2
```

while the `../` goes back a folder.